# best practice to pass object between a grid and edit page in Angular 8+

Tags: angular, ngrx

so i have a data grid with a typical edit button. a very typical scenario where this a create-edit-account component that will also be used to edit and existing component.

so when i click edit on a grid i navigate to create-edit-account component to use it for edit purposes as well.

upon clicking edit i navigate like this

```
 edit(account: BankAccount) {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/create-edit-account/' + account.id);
 }
```

but at the time i clicked edit i have a populated account object i want to pass it to the create-edit-account component.

**Question 1** what is the best practice in passing object while using parameterized routes in Angular 8+

**Question 2** how we tell a component that it is being used for edit or add. i learned that if i pass "0" in the route's id param we can consider it is being used as "new" . but is there a better approach ?

i also have an ngrx store implemented . so  **Question 3** would you recommend using an action dispatch with something called "account-updating" and passing in the object as an action param and subscribing it in the create-edit-account component and later dispatching "account-updated" action?

Answer (score 0):

We should be utilizing power of ngrx where its actually required. I mean where there is sharing of data being used my multiple components at same time in single view. Those kind of scenarios.

Your particular case is simple

Create a service, before navigation set this data in a property in that service, and in on init of your create-edit component get that data. In this data, you can set where creating account or editing account flag in same data object.

I you want it to retain data on refresh use localStorage or sessionStorage as per scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: you can use resolvers, they can fetch the data and pass it together with ActivatedRoute.

Q2: You should have an independent url for the edit mode, then the component can detect its state and switch between show / edit, also users can share desired page to show or to edit the component.

As an option you can have internal state in the component and a button that switches it to be show / edit. But in this case users always have to click the button.

Q3: For the thing you describe you should use ngrx effects. Then an effects listens to update request and performs it. Once the request has been finished it dispatches an action to set the updated entity in the store.